# Is there a generic ScreenSpaceEvent that captures all events?

Tags: cesiumjs

To react to specific space handlers I typically do this -

```
var fooHandler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(viewer.scene.canvas);
fooHandler.setInputAction(function(movement){
    // do stuff
}, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.WHEEL);
```

This function would be limited to WHEEL inputs. I have a couple of things that I need to do every time the camera changes position or height. I tried creating an event handler for the camera in a fashion similar to the above, and then calling `camera.positionCartographic` within that function, but to no avail.

Is there an event in Cesium that captures *any* movement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to use `ScreenSpaceEventHandler` to do this.  Instead, you subscribe to the `preRender` event and compare the camera position from last frame.  Here's some sample code for you:

```
var lastTime = Cesium.getTimestamp();
var lastPosition = viewer.scene.camera.position.clone();

function preRender(scene) {
    var time = Cesium.getTimestamp();
    var position = scene.camera.position;
    if (!Cesium.Cartesian3.equalsEpsilon(lastPosition, position, Cesium.Math.EPSILON4)) {
        document.getElementById('viewChanged').style.display = 'block';
        lastTime = time;
    } else if (time - lastTime > 250) {
        //hide the 'view changed' message after 250 ms of inactivity
        lastTime = time;
        document.getElementById('viewChanged').style.display = 'none';
    }
    lastPosition = position.clone();
}

viewer.scene.preRender.addEventListener(preRender);
```

We plan on adding a `viewChanged` event to Cesium some time soon, perhaps with 1.8, but this code will continue to work after that and you'll be able to switch to the event at your leisure.

If you want a live demo of the above code, see this port of the view changed Google Earth demo we did in Cesium: http://analyticalgraphicsinc.github.io/cesium-google-earth-examples/examples/viewchangeEvent.html

Comment: This works great in 3D mode, but in 2D the camera position, specifically the Z-axis, doesn't change. I'm looking for a solution but would love to hear your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
        _preRender = function (scene) {
        var currentPosition = scene.camera.position;

        if (!Cesium.Cartesian3.equalsEpsilon(_lastPosition, currentPosition, Cesium.Math.EPSILON4)) {
            _lastPosition = currentPosition.clone();

            if (typeof _positionChangeTimeout !== 'undefined' && _positionChangeTimeout !== null)
            {
                clearTimeout(_positionChangeTimeout);
            }

            var currentPositionCartographic = scene.camera.positionCartographic;

            _positionChangeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                if (typeof _positionChangeListener === 'function' && _positionChangeListener !== null)
                {
                    _positionChangeListener({
                        lat: Cesium.Math.toDegrees(currentPositionCartographic.latitude),
                        long: Cesium.Math.toDegrees(currentPositionCartographic.longitude),
                        zoomLevel: _calcZoomForAltitude(currentPositionCartographic.height, currentPositionCartographic.latitude)
                    });
                }
            }, 250);
        }
    }
```